# javascript skipping lines safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari

So the problem I'm having occurs only intermittently, and *only* in safari.

This works in all tested browsers other than safari, all the time.  In safari it works all the time when I have a breakpoint set in the code, but only about 1 in 10 tries when I don't have a breakpoint set.

The following function is called by the onchange of a radio button group.

```
function anl_tabs_submit() {
    document.getElementById("cssload-loader").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("anl_wholetable").style.opacity = 0.4;
    document.getElementById("anl_tab_form").submit();
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('tab');
    for (var i = 0; i< radios.length; i++){
        radios[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

The lines that are getting skipped are the first 2:

```
document.getElementById("cssload-loader").style.opacity = 1;
document.getElementById("anl_wholetable").style.opacity = 0.4;
```

I've in the html, the radio button group simulates tabs.  What I want is that when a user clicks a tab, the content in the tabs dims, and a hidden pacifier appears, then the form that the group is part of is submitted.

If I put alerts in various places in the code, the alerts always work, but the 2 opacity changes happen only occasionally (on safari).

Is this a safari problem, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Jeff

Comment: Is this code being triggered when the DOM is completely done loading? Try adding a setTimeout before document.getElementById("cssload-loader").style.opacity = 1; for one second and see if that does anything.

Comment: I'll try that, but when I put an alert before that element, it was still skipped, even if you waited a significant amount of time before closing the alert.

Comment: Still intermittent, however the delay happens, but the function inside the setTimeout() doesn't happen when it fails.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with whether the DOM is loaded or not.  I just loaded the page, then went to read questions on here, then went back a few minutes later, and it still failed on the first click (after having many minutes to load).

Comment: Also just discovered this is the case with Safari on Mac, but not Safari on an iPhone.

Comment: Ok, update in case this helps anybody help me:  In the above code, it's not the document.getElementById part that's not working.  I put console.log(document.getElementById("anl_wholetable").style); before any other lines in the script, and got valid style object in the console, so the only thing that it could be is just setting the opacity.  This is really confusing, because it seems that should be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured the problem out... finally!

The UI on Safari wasn't updating before I reached the submit line.  Here's how I fixed it (in case somebody has the same problem in the future:

```
function anl_tabs_submit(frm) {
    document.getElementById("cssload-loader").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("anl_wholetable").style.opacity = 0.4;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById(frm).submit();
        var radios = document.getElementsByName('tab');
        for (var i = 0; i< radios.length; i++){
            radios[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }, 0);

}
```

The important thing is the window.setTimeout which appears to give the browser time to update the window before continuing running the instructions in the second half of the script.